# Unable to put different text files creating different subfolders within a main folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, directory, subdirectory

I've written a script in python to scrape the first five titles of different posts from a webpage and then write the titles in individual text files and put them in five different subfolders within a desktop folder `DataStorage`.

Currently my following script can parse the titles of five posts and write them in five different text files and put them in a desktop folder `DataStorage`.

***How can I create five different subfolders within a main folder and put the text files in concerning subfolders?***

This is my attempt so far:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

dirf = r"C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\DataStorage" #The main folder in desktop
if not os.path.exists(dirf):os.makedirs(dirf)
os.chdir(dirf)

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink")[:5]:
    filename = item.text.split(" ")[0]
    with open(filename+'.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as filename:
        filename.write(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

dirf = r"C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\DataStorage"  # The main folder in desktop
if not os.path.exists(dirf):
    os.makedirs(dirf)
os.chdir(dirf)

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink")[:5]:
    filename = item.text.split(" ")[0]
    curr_dir = os.path.join(dirf, filename)
    os.makedirs(curr_dir)
    filepath = os.path.join(curr_dir, filename+'.txt')
    with open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(item.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

*never* use `os.chdir` if you can avoid it, which is: *most of the time/always*.

Plus it prevents you to understand the logic of file paths out of current directory.

Prefer using absolute path on the files you're reading/writing.

So remove

```
os.chdir(dirf)
```

now change this:

```
with open(filename+'.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as filename:
```

by

```
subdir = os.path.join(dirf,item)
if os.path.exists(subdir):
    os.mkdir(subdir)   # create first time
with open(os.path.join(subdir,filename+'.txt'),'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   f.write(item.text)
```

where `item` is your subdirectory relative path (it has to comply to current filesystem rules, which isn't 100% guaranteed since it originates from a html file). Also note that you shouldn't use `filename` again for the file *handle*. I usually use `f` or `filehandle`

Answer (score 0):

To make a directory, you can use `os.mkdir(PATH)`. To create the file, you can `open` the file with `w+` permission which will create the file if it doesn't exist and also rewrite the file if it exists.